# multiply replace in mysql update query with join table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have some tables:

```
#comments
| id| text     |
----------------
| 1 | aa bb cc |

#words
| id| word |
------------
| 1 | aa   |
| 2 | bb   |
```

Then I run this query

```
UPDATE comments AS c
        LEFT JOIN
    words AS w ON (c.text LIKE CONCAT('%', w.word, '%')) 
SET 
    c.text = REPLACE(
        c.text,
        w.word,
        CONCAT('<b>', w.word, '</b>')
    )
```

In result I have this data in comments table

```
| id| text            |
-----------------------
| 1 | <b>aa</b> bb cc |
```

How change my query to get in result some this?

```
| id| text                   |
------------------------------
| 1 | <b>aa</b> <b>bb</b> cc |
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit too long for a comment.

The simple answer is that you cannot do what you want with a single MySQL `update` statement.  You have a situation where you have multiple rows in the `#words` table that match a given row in the `#comments` table.  What happens is explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html):

> For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named
>   in table_references that satisfy the conditions. **Each matching row is
>   updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times.**

This can be accomplished in some databases using recursive CTEs.  And, it might be possible if you had a regular expression replacement function.  But, neither of those are options in MySQL.

That leaves you with two choices.  The first is to write a stored procedure and do the `update` in a loop.  The second is to fix your data structure so you are not storing lists of things in a string.